# dask dataframe count values

Tags: python, dask

In my **dask** dataframe I have a `Series` of lists. So the column triggers looks like the following:

```
['a', 'b']
['c']
['a', 'c']
```

I wish to count the occurences of each unique element within the Series so that I end up with:

```
{'a' : 2,
'b' : 1
'c' : 2}
```

The only way that I have managed to get it to work is by doing:

```
from collections import Counter

a = df.triggers.loc[:1000000]
b = a.sum()
trigger_counts = Counter(b.compute())
```

I had to do `.loc[:10000]` to keep the computations down to a reasonable time. I have a feeling that I can do this faster. `.value_counts()` does not work on `b` as it is of type `dask.dataframe.core.Scalar` and does not have that attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You can try in dask:

```
  import dask.dataframe as dd
  ddf = dd.read_csv('file.csv')
  ddf.country.value_counts().compute().plot(kind='bar')
```

Where "country" in my case is a column.

You will get a nice plot on top!

Comment: Hello, the only problem with this is that I have a Series of lists. So if you look at my example I want 'a' to be counted twice. Whereas with your code I believe you will get `['a', 'b'] : 1, ['c']: 1, ['a', 'c']:1`.

Comment: @Sachin_ruk, what you could do is to apply some kind of map function that works with collections.Counter. This would than work like typical map reduce. --> map distributed -->combine distributed counter objects --> reduce to a final set.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following:

```
import pandas as pd

triggers_dummies = (pd.get_dummies(df.triggers.apply(pd.Series)
                                              .stack()).sum(level=0))
counts = np.sum(triggers_dummies, axis=0).to_dict()
```

Comment: Won't this convert the dask dataframe to pandas though. It's a pretty big dataframe that won't fit in memory at the moment.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work. Get the error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'stack'`